# Laravel 4 include - php echo - in file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, echo

In laravel 4. how do you include this line

```
<?php echo include_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/pa_antiadblock.php'); ?>
```

Of corse, this code will load an popunder ad, on an similar page to [this](http://movie-watch.online/online-movies/2936-i-am-legend)

Comment: Because this is not a **real** answer: why don't you use a blade and include that?

Comment: Besides: you **do** know that it will not magically add the share function to your page right?

Comment: If you want to include page then go with Laravel syntax its easy and flexible for blade also.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it just adds JavaScript to website
The easy way would be add it into blade view.
However if it push headers to the request you should send them before anything else so put it before returning the view